# Why does my website loads infinitely after I tried the sleep method?

Tags: php, sleep

So I was playing with the sleep method of php. I coded `sleep(99999);` Now my website won't load lol. Is it because of that? How can I fix it?

Comment: I think you can just restart apache, or php-fpm if you are using php-fpm. And why in the world would you try that.

Comment: So is it a server thing then? I have tried to try another url for the same website. But it still does not load. I am using a hosting company called Strato at the moment.

Comment: You must restart your server. Or, it will just be stuck in an endless loop until the sleep time ends.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana It works now thanks

Comment: I have posted it as an answer for you to accept it :)

Comment: Are you using sessions?

Comment: @user3783243, the issue is already fixed btw

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana The issue hasn't been explained though.. likely https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php is the culprit of the behavior OP described

Comment: @user3783243, it is obvious that they used `sleep(99999);`, and probably, for some odd reason, their memory might've been a little full because of this little thing. Or, due to that they were using sessions as you told??

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana If `sleep(99999)` was removed the behavior would still persist for `99999` seconds if the session write was not closed.

Comment: @user3783243 yes you are right. It won't load the updated page until the sleep is over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just restart apache, or php-fpm if you are using php-fpm. 
And why in the world would you try that!

You must restart your server if restarting your web server didn't work. Or, it will just be stuck in a delay until the sleep time ends.

I would advise you not to play with a production server. Use a test server for these tests. Because it is not as easy to reset these issues.

For example, when you are using shared hosting, you cannot restart apache yourself.

### How do I setup a test server:

Install some software like XAMPP if you are using Windows in your home PC. Or, if you are using Linux, you can just install apache and php using the following commands on:

- Ubuntu/Debian: `sudo apt install apache2 php`
- CentOS/Fedora: `sudo yum install epel-release`, and `sudo yum install httpd php` or `sudo dnf install httpd php`
- Arch Linux/Manjaro: `sudo pacman -S apache php php-apache`

Comment: `sleep` does not create an endless loop until the end of time. It simply creates an execution delay for a defined time. There is no looping involved.

Comment: @MarkusAO, I did mention that it ends after the sleep duration. But, I urgently typed in the answer, before this question could be closed.